# Wireless driver not working for Broadcom BCM43224 after latest update

Tags: wireless

So, I did the latest update, and now my wireless driver isn't working. In the taskbar area, it shows that there is no device. However, when in my Win8 partition and when using an older version of Linux, it is working fine. How would I fix this? Also, here is the output showing the specifics of my wireless driver:

```
~$ lspci -vvnn | grep 14e4
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43224 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4353] (rev 01)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please get a temporary ethernet connection and do:

```
    sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
    sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
    sudo modprobe wl
```

You should be all set.

Comment: Would I be able to do this using a previous version of the Linux kernel? Or would this fix only apply to the kernel version I am using at the time?

Comment: It should work with every kernel version.

Comment: So now we have a solution ,but what was the reason for the module not being built? I've seen the same thing on multiple laptops with broadcom cards

Comment: There is a glitch somewhere in the bcmwl package that doesn't correctly install the needed headers. I'm sure you could find and add to a bug somewhere.